# multiple color in facet grid label

Tags: python, colors, facet-grid

I would like to have different color in the label of my plot. For example if the mean is lower than 100 then the title of the plot is red, if its higher than 500 the title is green.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

There is my python lines:

```
g.map(plot_rectangle, 'moyenne', 'Q15','Q85','moyenneG')
g.set_titles('{col_name}',x=0.5, y=1,size=15, alpha=0.7,color='green')
```

It's only working when color is equal to only one color, its not working when color is equal to a list of color.

I wold like to find a way to assign multiple color, someone knows how to do that ?